# How to run docker image one time in aws on some event and shut down it after that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I need to know how can I run docker image in aws one time on some event(file upload).

For example:
I uploaded files to S3 and then I need to run my docker image one time. I know that I can do something like that with ESC tasks, but in this case I will have constantly running EC2, it's too expensive.

How to run docker image once on every file upload and shutdown it after its running?

P.S. docker image should have at least 8GB memory for working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two major announcements for Lambdas in ReInvent 2020 solves your usecase.

- Usage of [Containers in Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/)
- Increase memory limit from 3 GB to [10 GB](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-supports-10gb-memory-6-vcpu-cores-lambda-functions/#:%7E:text=Customer%20Enablement-,AWS%20Lambda%20now%20supports%20up%20to%2010%20GB%20of%20memory,vCPU%20cores%20for%20Lambda%20Functions&text=AWS%20Lambda%20customers%20can%20now,previous%20limit%20of%203%2C008%20MB.)

you can easily trigger a Lambda function from S3 Upload, [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) is a tutorial

---

Older approach: Triggering an ECS task from Cloudwatch Event Rule, [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html) is a tutorial

Comment: Running it in Lambda isn't exactly a solution, as you need to do some work with the container to integrate it with the AWS Lambda runtime.

Comment: I agree, there is little overhead to write additional lines Dockerfile , to copy artifacts to certain location and use their specefic base images.. if use case doesn't suite, we can always run as ECS Task from AWS Batch or directly from event rule.